# How to customize allure report name?

Tags: postman, allure, postman-testcase, postman-newman

I am running a postman collection using newman and generating the reports using Allure framework. My command looks something like this:

```
newman run $collection_filename -e $environment_filename -r allure --reporter-allure-export "$reportsFolder"
allure generate --clean $reportsFolder
```

I looked into the [allure github repo](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-js/tree/master/packages/newman-reporter-allure) but couldn't find any command line argument/technique to change the name of the allure report generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

allure generate --clean **--report-name 'Custom Report Name'**

**NOTE**: You must have Allure version 2.26.0 or latest

[image: Dashboard Screenshot]